# ClassLoader problem when using GWT RequestFactory with Grails

Tags: java, gwt, grails, classloader, requestfactory

In order to get GWT RequestFactory running with Grails, I am using the following approach:

```
class GwtController extends RequestFactoryServlet {

    public GwtController() {
        super()
    }

    def index = {
        doPost request, response
    }

    @Override
    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return ServletContextHolder.servletContext
    }

    @Override
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return new DummyServletConfig(getServletContext(),"grails");
    }
}
```

where DummyServletConfig is a simple implementation of `ServletConfig`

This is working when deploying the app to tomcat. However, using testing or development mode, it is not. I was required to adjust the GWT Servlet in order to prevent it from using the wrong Class Loader:

In line 46 I changed

```
private static final RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator validator =
  new RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator(log,
      new RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.ClassLoaderLoader(
          ServiceLayer.class.getClassLoader()));
```

to

```
private static final RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator validator = new RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator(
  log, new RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator.ClassLoaderLoader(
      Thread.currentThread()
                        .getContextClassLoader()));
```

Otherwise, it wouldn't find my Domain classes (which apparently do not reside in the GrailsRootLoader but in the Thread's class loader).

Now I would like to revert my GWT servlet to the official binary released by Google and I wonder how I can fix the incorrect ClassLoader in Grails or make the RequestFactoryServlet work correctly without altering the GWT source.

Comment: Hi fabus, have you managed to using GWT RequestFactory with a Grails backend? Do you have any tip on doing that? I am really interested in GWT and Grails together, but it seems not easy to integrate the two. Tks

Comment: Yes, we have. The trick is using GWT 2.4 RC1 or using the ServiceLayer to override the default RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator as outlined above. Let me know if you have troubles (or raise another question)

Comment: Tks fabus. Do you use grails gwt plugin? Or do you just have your GWT classes in grails' java src folder? Cause GWT and Grails have different folder structures, so.... if you want I can raise a question just for this...

Comment: yeah, simply using gwt plugin, it creates /src/gwt for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that GWT 2.3 will fix your problem:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6092

Comment: it doesn't since the RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator used by ResolverServiceLayer is still using ServiceLayer.class.getClassLoader() - I will file it as a bug now.